# modifying links from module in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

On my drupal site, there is a page with some modular blocks, and they output a set of links.  In my module I need to be able to append some GET parameters to those links.  How should I go about handling this?

The appending has to be done in the module as I have PHP code there that generates the parameters.

Thanks

EDIT:
After some investigation, I've found what was creating the links.  It's a field collection I believe.  The link itself is a field value.  I've tried modifying it directly in field--field_modular_box.tpl.php by doing:

```
foreach ($items as $delta => $item): 
  $item['entity']['field_collection_item'][$key]['field_mod_box_logo']['field_mod_box_call']['und'][0]['display_url'] .= "&" . generate_token();
endforeach;
```

But this doesn't actually change the link that is displayed.  I've checked and this is the correct template that generates the links.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? Did you create the modules that create the links i.e. can you edit them directly or do you need to modify them externally using a hook?

Comment: I've updated my question to address some of your questions.  I need to modify them using PHP code, which I guess means I can do it in a template, or module, but not in the Drupal interface.